# Can I trick access to private C++ class member variables?

Tags: c++, private, member-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing private members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726096/accessing-private-members)
>   [Is it possible to access private members of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729363/is-it-possible-to-access-private-members-of-a-class)

Is there a good (yes I know this is ugly) way to hack to the private data members of a class?

One brute force approach is to copy the header file and in my copy change private to public.  But would there be a better way, say doing

```
#define private public
```

or something else?

Comment: One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729363/is-it-possible-to-access-private-members-of-a-class

Comment: The better way is to change the private access specifier to public. :)

Comment: According to the C++ standard, this could even *change the layout* of your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots and lots of ways of doing this - all of them bad. Protection in C++ is there for a purpose, to prevent you from making mistakes. It is not there as a security measure. If you want public access, just make things public!

Comment: Totally agree with Neil.