# Accessing a c++ parent class's private member

Tags: c++, class, private, member, undefined-behavior

I have a basic C++ question that unfortunately baffles me. Recently I ran across an article that uses down-casting to access a class's private member using down-casting. My question is why does it work?

Given that I have a parent class P with a private member m_p of type dummy* then the method used was to create a hack class hackP as follows:

```
class hackP: public P {
public:
dummy *m_p;
};
```

which apparently gains access to `class P` private member `m_p` using a code snippet like

```
P parent = ...;
hackP *hp = (hackP*)&parent;
// access parent m_p as hp->m_p
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Umm, m_p is public?  What's the hack?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: It's public in `hackP`, but presumably occupying the same offset as something private in `P`. That's the hack.

Comment: You could do it by making hackP not inherit from P as long as the classes between HP and P aligned perfectly using that type-cast (not a good idea).  But the inheritance part baffles me as that should change the signature in memory around enough to break that.

Comment: Errors in the code aside (as @MichaelDorgan mentioned, there should be no inheritance) this is Undefined Behaviour. As such, and as far as the Standard is concerned, the only reason why it works is *pure luck*.

Comment: @PaulTarr: Do you have a link to said article? I think something got lost in the translation.

Comment: GotW #76 seems relevant: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, make that an answer.  It fits the bill perfectly here and taught me a thing or two to boot!  :)

Comment: @Fred The original article that sparked this question is at http://pareis.com/2010/03/23/accessing-the-original-webkit-api-in-qtwebkit-hybrid-apps/ and is under the section titled "alternate access".

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `GotW #76` [Uses and Abuses of Access Rights](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm) cover this topic pretty well and I have to say I picked up some interesting tid bits that I did not know from it.

This article [Access to private members. That's easy!](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html) takes a bit more effort to wrap your head around but seems more flexible.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834451/1708801) from this thread [Is private member hacking defined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834414/is-private-member-hacking-defined-behaviour) which is very similar but not identical seems to indicate this is undefined behavior since the layout would not guaranteed to be the same between  `access-qualifier` sections. From the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), section `9.2` *Class members* says (*emphasis mine*):

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access
>   control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object. **The order of allocation of non-static
>   data members with different access control is unspecified** (11).

Comment: The references GotW #76 and private member hacking defined behavior are much appreciated. The latter especially. I'll just have to try the hack out with my compiler and see what happens since I am working with a supplied dll and cannot recompile it. Thanks for the reply.