# Secure credential storage in python

Tags: python, security, reflection, storage, credentials

### The attack

One possible threat model, in the context of credential storage, is an attacker which has the ability to :

- inspect any (user) process memory
- read local (user) files

AFAIK, the consensus on this type of attack is that it's impossible to prevent (since the credentials must be stored in memory for the program to actually use them), but there's a couple of techniques to mitigate it:

- minimize the amount of time the sensitive data is stored in memory
- overwrite the memory as soon as the data is not needed anymore
- mangle the data in memory, keep moving it, and other security through obscurity measures

### Python in particular

The first technique is easy enough to implement, possibly [through a keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring)  (hopefully kernel space storage)

The second one is not achievable at all without writing a C module, to the best of my knowledge (but I'd love to be proved wrong here, or to have a list of existing modules)

The third one is tricky.

In particular, python being a language with very powerful introspection  and reflection capabilities, it's difficult to prevent access to the credentials to anyone which can execute python code in the interpreter process.

There seems to be a consensus that [there's no way to enforce private attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551038/private-implementation-class-in-python) and that [attempts at it will at best annoy other programmers who are using your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365193/is-this-code-truly-private-python/10365338#10365338).

### The question

Taking all this into consideration, how does one securely store authentication credentials using python? What are the best practices? Can something be done about the language "everything is public" philosophy? I know ["we're all consenting adults here"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics), but should we be forced to choose between sharing our passwords with an attacker and using another language?

Comment: As you acknowledge that given the assumptions this kind of attack is impossible to prevent, I don't think the choice you present at the end is real. Given the assumptions, you *must* share your passwords with the attacker (whichever language you use).

Comment: @Michael Put into an absolute sense, yes, you share the passwords with the attacker whichever language you use. But that's like saying that, because a couple of people in the world can crack any lock, I might as well don't spend the money on any front door. As put by Bruce Schneier, [avoiding threats is black and white; avoiding risk is continuous](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram-0005.html). I'm not looking for a panacea here, just something "good enough"

Comment: Python Keyring protects secrets *from other users* of the same computer, and for this purpose, it's very good.

However *all* Python applications running as a given user share access to the keyring. In other words, all a hacker has to do is use keyring and they can read the secrets that your Python program stored in it. Oops.

Comment: It's worth noting that `private`, `protected`, etc., access modifiers in languages such as Java or C# have *absolutely nothing* to do with security. They are there to make the API more manageable and communicate clearly to other devs and the IDE what can/should be used where.

Comment: C# has a special class called [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that avoids storing sensitive data as plain text in memory, and wipes this part of memory when done.

In Java you would have to use `char[]` instead of `String` and handle everything manually, or use a library, such as [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/).

The real culprit here is the way strings are implemented in almost all programming languages (stored as plain text in memory, immutable and, thus, when modified a new string has to be created elsewhere, etc.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two very different reasons why you might store authentication credentials:

1. To authenticate *your* user: For example, you only allow the user access to the services after the user authenticates to your program
2. To authenticate *the program* with another program or service: For example, the user starts your program which then accesses the user's email over the Internet using IMAP.

In the first case, you should never store the password (or an encrypted version of the password). Instead, you should *hash* the password with a high-quality salt and ensure that the hashing algorithm you use is computationally expensive (to prevent dictionary attacks) such as PBKDF2 or bcrypt. See [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for many more details. If you follow this approach, even if the hacker retrieves the salted, slow-hashed token, they can't do very much with it.

In the second case, there are a number of things done to make secret discovery harder (as you outline in your question), such as:

- Keeping secrets encrypted until needed, decrypting on demand, then re-encrypting immediately after
- Using address space randomization so each time the application runs, the keys are stored at a different address
- Using the OS keystores
- Using a "hard" language such as C/C++ rather than a VM-based, introspective language such as Java or Python

Such approaches are certainly better than nothing, but a skilled hacker will break it sooner or later.

### Tokens

From a theoretical perspective, authentication is the act of proving that the person challenged is who they say they are. Traditionally, this is achieved with a shared secret (the password), but there are other ways to prove yourself, including:

- [Out-of-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band) authentication. For example, where I live, when I try to log into my internet bank, I receive a [one-time password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) (OTP) as a SMS on my phone. In this method, I prove I am by virtue of owning a specific telephone number
- [Security token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token): To log in to a service, I have to press a button on my token to get a OTP which I then use as my password.
- Other devices:

  - [SmartCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card), in particular as used by the US DoD where it is called the [CAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Access_Card). Python has a module called [pyscard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) to interface to this
  - [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication#Security_aspects) device

And a more complete list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication)

The commonality between all these approaches is that the end-user controls these devices and the secrets never actually leave the token/card/phone, and certainly are never stored in your program. This makes them much more secure.

### Session stealing

However (there is always a however):

Let us suppose you manage to secure the login so the hacker cannot access the security tokens. Now your application is happily interacting with the secured service. Unfortunately, if the hacker can run arbitrary executables on your computer, the hacker can hijack your session for example by injecting additional commands into your valid use of the service. In other words, while you have protected the password, it's entirely irrelevant because the hacker still gains access to the 'secured' resource.

This is a very real threat, as the multiple cross-site scripting attacks have shows (one example is [U.S. Bank and Bank of America Websites Vulnerable](http://news.softpedia.com/news/U-S-Bank-and-Bank-of-America-Websites-Vulnerable-112148.shtml), but there are countless more).

### Secure proxy

As discussed above, there is a fundamental issue in keeping the credentials of an account on a third-party service or system so that the application can log onto it, especially if the only log-on approach is a username and password.

One way to partially mitigate this by delegating the communication to the service to a secure proxy, and develop a secure sign-on approach between the application and proxy. In this approach

- The application uses a PKI scheme or two-factor authentication to sign onto the secure proxy
- The user adds security credentials to the third-party system to the secure proxy. The credentials are never stored in the application
- Later, when the application needs to access the third-party system, it sends a request to the proxy. The proxy logs on using the security credentials and makes the request, returning results to the application.

The disadvantages to this approach are:

- The user may not want to trust the secure proxy with the storage of the credentials
- The user may not trust the secure proxy with the data flowing through it to the third-party application
- The application owner has additional infrastructure and hosting costs for running the proxy

### Some answers

So, on to specific answers:

> How does one securely store authentication credentials using python?

- If storing a password for the application to authenticate the user, use a PBKDF2 algorithm, such as https://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/
- If storing a password/security token to access another service, then there is no absolutely secure way.
- However, consider switching authentication strategies to, for example the smartcard, using, eg, [pyscard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/). You can use smartcards to both authenticate a user to the application, and also securely authenticate the application to another service with X.509 certs.

> Can something be done about the language "everything is public" philosophy? I know "we're all consenting adults here", but should we be forced to choose between sharing our passwords with an attacker and using another language?

IMHO there is nothing wrong with writing a *specific* module in Python that does it's damnedest to hide the secret information, making it a right bugger for others to reuse (annoying other programmers *is its purpose*). You could even code large portions in C and link to it. However, don't do this for other modules for obvious reasons.

Ultimately, though, if the hacker has control over the computer, there is no privacy on the computer at all. Theoretical worst-case is that your program is running in a VM, and the hacker has complete access to *all* memory on the computer, including the BIOS and graphics card, and can step your application though authentication to discover its secrets.

Given no absolute privacy, the rest is just obfuscation, and the level of protection is simply how hard it is obfuscated vs. how much a skilled hacker wants the information. And we all know how [that ends](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-57563484-75/windows-rt-jailbreak-tool-unleashed-online/), even for [custom hardware](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/25/sony-ps3-hacked-for-good-master-keys-revealed/) and [billion-dollar products](http://www.ibtimes.com/ios-6-61-untethered-jailbreak-evasi0n-be-released-monday-algorithm-used-progress-bar-hints-12pm-est).

> Using Python keyring

While this will quite securely manage the key with respect to other applications, *all Python applications* share access to the tokens. This is not in the slightest bit secure to the type of attack you are worried about.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm authenticating a non-interactive program which authenticates itself to a service I have no control over, but using certificates instead of passwords (fundamentally, any different authentication token than the user's), would, indeed, be a great idea. A obfuscating C module also seems like a reasonable compromise. Thanks for clarifying that python keyring access is shared - the documentation doesn't make this fact as obvious as it should

Comment: Aaah, thanks @goncalopp, understand the problem a little better. One additional option would be to write a proxy for the service you need to authenticate to. Your proxy would authenticate to the service on behalf of your program, and relay requests and their responses. Then you can write a secure authentication mechanism between your application and the service proxy. Would that work? If so, I'd be happy to update the answer.

Comment: It wouldn't be a good idea in my particular use case, since then the user would need to delegate its credentials to a third party (the proxy) - it is much easier to secure the proxy than a client's computer, but it's a (legal) risk in itself, and demands some amount of trust. I think it may be a worthwhile addition to the answer, though - I tried to be general in my question purposefully, so it applied to the largest number of people possible

Comment: @goncalopp: Thanks, I've updated my answer for the benefit of the community. Sorry that the proxy idea might not be a solution for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in this field and am really just looking to solve the same problem that you are, but it looks like something like [Hashicorp's Vault](https://hashicorp.com/blog/vault.html) might be able to help out quite nicely.

In particular WRT to the problem of storing credentials for 3rd part services. e.g.:

> In the modern world of API-driven everything, many systems also support programmatic creation of access credentials. Vault takes advantage of this support through a feature called dynamic secrets: secrets that are generated on-demand, and also support automatic revocation.
>
> For Vault 0.1, Vault supports dynamically generating AWS, SQL, and Consul credentials.

More links:

- [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault)
- [Vault Website](https://www.vaultproject.io)
- [Use Cases](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/use-cases.html)